# CoffeeScript - NodeJS unable to resolve localhost or 127.0.0.1

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am working on Windows 8.1, and have NodeJS 0.10 installed. I installed Coffee-Script, and used this simple example from http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/networking/basic-http-client

```
http = require 'http'

http.get ( host: 'www.google.com' ), (res) ->
    console.log res.statusCode
# Returns: 200
```

However, when I use my localhost, or 127.0.0.1 at the port of 4567 to test out my Sinatra page, I receive a DNS error.

```
http = require 'http'

http.get ( host: 'http://127.0.0.1:4567' ), (res) ->
    console.log res.statusCode
```

and the error is:

```
$> coffee http-request.coffee

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
  at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
  at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

This is the Ruby Sinatra app

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    erb :index
end

__END__

@@ index
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

I have gone and edited the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and made 127.0.0.1 resolve to localhost, but I still receive the error above. What should I try to do next?

-- Update --
After looking at Christian Fritz's answer, I got a different result now.

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got your invocation of `http.get` wrong. Either actually name the host, or just use the shorthand where you use a URL:

```
http.get ( 'http://127.0.0.1:4567' ), (res) ->
    console.log res.statusCode
```

Comment: I just made an update to the post. I did try that and got a different error, updated in the post.

Comment: @Pred: what happens when you do `curl http://127.0.0.1:4567` on the command line? (cygwin)